# Not show title in Woocommerce specific product category page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hide, categories, title

I've tried a lot to achieve this but I can't!
I need to remove the page title or entry title for some specific categories with css but the title's still there.

[image]

I tried:

`.catid-444 .entry-title  {
visibility: hidden;
}`

`.category-444 .entry-title  {
visibility: hidden;
}`

`.catid-444 h1.entry-title {
    display: none;
}`

Even with `!important` but nothing happens. Title's still there.

```
<h1 class="entry-title">Iron Studios</h1>
```

Is using this code:

```
.page-title.color-scheme-light .entry-title {
color: #767676;
}

.page-title > .container .entry-title {
font-family: Yantramanav;
font-weight: 300;
}
.page-title.color-scheme-light .entry-title {
color: #fff;
}
.title-size-default .entry-title {
font-size: 30px;
text-align: left;
font-weight: normal;
padding-top: 32px;
padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```

Thank you guys.

Comment: Can you give this a try? .term-444 .entry-title {
    display: none;
} 
a url to the page can be handy otherwise, because now it is a bit of a blind guess

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much my friend.